# Is there a simpler way to code a complex function?

Tags: r

I have a dataset I am working on looking at sepsis in a patient population. In this dataset, each row represents a day that is tracked by column `DAY_TIMEFRAME` where 0 is the first day of admission and onward. Patients are grouped by all the rows that share the same value in column `mrn_deid`. I have a column `sep_epi` that represents if the day this row represents had the diagnosis of sepsis present. I have a column called `first_sep_epi` that represents if this is this patients first episode of sepsis chronologically. I have a column that is if the patient had received antibiotics that day labeled `abx_yes`. I have a column `abx_6_days` that is a sum of the amount of days over the past six days that the patient has received antibiotics, not including the current day.

```
| first_sep_epi| sep_epi || abx_yes | abx_6_days || mrn_deid | DAY_TIMEFRAME |
| --------     | --------|| ------- |  --------  || -------- |    --------   |
|     0        |    0    ||   0     |       0    ||     1    |        0      |
|     1        |    1    ||   1     |       0    ||     1    |        1      |
|     0        |    0    ||   1     |       1    ||     1    |        2      |
|     0        |    1    ||   1     |       2    ||     1    |        3      |
```

I am trying to create a new column called sub_sep_epi that would identify subsequent episodes of sepsis after the first episode in which antibiotics have not been given for at least 6 days. I need for the code to check that the mrn_deid value 6 row above the current matches the current row as this means they are the same patient. Then it would need to check sep_epi for a 1 as this would represent an episode of sepsis. Then it needs to check if this is the first_sep_epi as we only want subsequent episodes not the first. Then it needs to check if the abx_6_days column is 0 or ≥1, as a 0 means that the patient has not received antibiotics recently. I am new to coding and this is probably the most complicated thing I've tried to do in R, so I would appreciate any insight or ideas for how to approach this.

```
    cx_neg_list <- cx_neg_list %>%
    group_by(mrn_deid) %>%
    arrange(DAY_TIMEFRAME) %>%
    mutate(
    sub_sep_epi = if_else(
      all(lag(mrn_deid, n = 1:6) == mrn_deid, na.rm = TRUE) & 
        row_number() >= 6 &
        sep_epi == 0 &
        first_sep_epi == 0 &
        abx_6_days == 0,
      1, 0
    )
    ) %>%
    select(first_sep_epi, sep_epi, abx_yes, abx_6_days, sub_sep_epi, everything()) %>%
    ungroup()
```

The error I received back is:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `sub_sep_epi = if_else(...)`.
ℹ In group 1: `mrn_deid = "1"`.
Caused by error in `lag()`:
! `n` must be a whole number, not an integer vector.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `sub_sep_epi = if_else(...)`.
ℹ In group 1: `mrn_deid = "1"`.
Caused by error in `lag()`:
! `n` must be a whole number, not an integer vector.
---
Backtrace:
 ▆
1. ├─... %>% ungroup()
2. ├─dplyr::ungroup(.)
3. ├─dplyr::select(...)
4. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
5. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
6. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
7. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
8. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
9. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
```

10. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
11. ├─dplyr::if_else(...)
12. │ └─dplyr:::check_logical(condition)
13. │   └─rlang::is_logical(x)
14. └─dplyr::lag(n = 1:6)

Comment: Just to clarify, you're getting this error because `n = 1:6` is not an acceptable argument to use with `lag()`. `n` must be a single integer, e.g. `lag(x, n = 6)`